# Programmatic Export with Indeterminate Table Structure from SQL Server 2008 using T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, ssis, export

I have searched for an answer to this, and one seems not to exist.
Problem:
  A website is querying a database and unable to return results (as an export to Excel) in a timely fashion.  This is primarily due to result set size.  I'd like to set up a background process to 'ping' for waiting queries and execute them one-by-one, dumping data into a location to be downloaded from.  The 'pinging' task can be handled a whole host of ways.  My original ideal solution was a trigger (alternatively, a SQL Server Agent task) that exported the data to the filesystem.  But I have run into an issue where I don't know how to set up an amorphous output to the filesystem with a simple T-SQL statement.

SSIS is apparently the standard solution to this.  I don't know enough about SSIS to know whether it will handle what I want it to do, but I have been told the queries are too great in number / various in output for that to be a feasible solution.

xp_cmdshell can be run to do a BCP export.  This works fine, but apparently opens a security hole.

Previous solutions:
  A solution I used years ago, DTS passing data straight to the operating system, seems to have been disabled in SQL Server 2008/ 2012.  I also used to be able to use sp_makewebtask to export data directly to the filesystem but no longer can do that either.

Current solution
  I am writing a PowerShell script tied to some SQL tables and stored procedures to manage execution.  This seems like a non-ideal solution; I'm curious as to whether I have missed something.  Is there an easy way to set up SSIS to export data without a structure?  A way to create an Excel file on the fly and fill it with data?

The answer seems to be No.

Comment: You can still export data to files on OS using SSIS in 2008/2012.

Comment: Well aware.  I'd just been told that I couldn't do it with arbitrary columns from the command line easily.  And for some reason SSIS is not included in my SQL install.

Answer (score 0):

You can export to CSV instead of Excel (because Excel opens CSV files easily), but they don't have any formatting. You can set up SSIS (or BCP in a scheduled task) to export in the CSV file a single column which already contains the commas and the text delimiters, so the data would be presented by Excel in separate columns.

Comment: SSIS to a single comma-delimited column sounds like the smart way to go.  Do you have an example of how that would work?